# Android App Counter Button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-button

When I try to open this page it crashes. I have tried to make this button count various ways and can't get it to count! I have tried all kinds of tutorials by thenewboston and other people but it doesn't work for me.

## **Medical.java**

```
package com.fullcyclestudios.rust;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Medical extends ActionBarActivity {

Button add, sub;
int counter;
TextView textView;
TextView quantityDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medical);

    add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addButtonMedical);
    sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.minusButtonMedical);
    quantityDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewQuantityMedical);
    counter=1;

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            quantityDisplay.setText("it"+counter);
        }
    });

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            quantityDisplay.setText("it"+counter);
        }
    });



    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.medical, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_medical,
                container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

 /** Bandage button */
public String bandageMaterials(View view) 
{
    String materials = "Bandage\r\n\r\n2 Cloth";
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMatMedical); 
    textView.setText(materials);
    return materials;
}

 /** Small Medkit button */
public String smallMedkitMaterials(View view) 
{
    String materials = "Small Medkit\r\n\r\n2 Cloth\r\n2 Blood";
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMatMedical); 
    textView.setText(materials);
    return materials;
}

/** Large Medkit button */
public String largeMedkitMaterials(View view) 
{
    String materials = "Large Medkit\r\n\r\n3 Cloth\r\n3 Blood";
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMatMedical); 
    textView.setText(materials);
    return materials;
}
}
```

## **fragment_medical.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.fullcyclestudios.rust.Medical$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewMedical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/bandageButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="@string/bandage"
    android:onClick="bandageMaterials" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/smallMedkitButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="@string/smallMedkit"
    android:onClick="smallMedkitMaterials" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/largeMedkitButton"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:text="@string/largeMedkit"
    android:onClick="largeMedkitMaterials" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMatMedical"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:background="@color/gray"
    android:text="@string/blank" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewQuantityMedical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/minusButtonMedical"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/minusButtonMedical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addButtonMedical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/minusButtonMedical"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addButtonMedical"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addButtonMedical"
    android:text="@string/minus"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addButtonMedical"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewMatMedical"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textViewMatMedical"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## **ERRORS**

```
06-08 16:10:38.890: W/dalvikvm(855): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a40ba8)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855): Process: com.fullcyclestudios.rust, PID: 855
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fullcyclestudios.rust/com.fullcyclestudios.rust.Medical}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at com.fullcyclestudios.rust.Medical.onCreate(Medical.java:33)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-08 16:10:38.990: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  ... 11 more
06-08 16:10:43.330: I/Process(855): Sending signal. PID: 855 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_medical);

```
add=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addButtonMedical);
sub=(Button) findViewById(R.id.minusButtonMedical);
```

but from what you post: addButtonMedical and minusButtonMedical are inside fragment_medical and not activity_medical xml layout!